# Calling parameter from main class to another file in another file (1 package)

Tags: java

I've 2 java file like this:

**Test1.java**

```
package beiobligasi;

public class Test1 {

        public static void main( String args[] ) {
            Test2.Test2(args);
            String var1 = "Only test!";
        }
    }
```

**Test2.java**

```
package beiobligasi;

public class Test2 {
    static void Test2(String[] args) {
        String source = new Test1().var1;
        System.out.println("Testing result = " + source);
    }
}
```

Basically, i want to use parameter from main in **Test1.java** then call it in a class Test2 from **Test2.java**.

The program will be work if i change the string parameter from **Test1.java** outside the main like this:

**Test1.java**

```
package beiobligasi;

public class Test1 {
        String var1 = "Only test!";

        public static void main( String args[] ) {
            Test2.Test2(args);
        }
    }
```

But i need to use the string parameter inside the main, bcs i'll use it for another function...
Can anyone help me to fix the code, so i can use the string parameter still in main?

Comment: You want to do some more studying. Start working through the basics from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ... you see, you are asking a super basic question; and that is not really what this site is about.

Comment: If you declare var1 inside the main method, it is a local variable. That is it will only be visible / accessible inside that scope (in this case the main method). If you move it outside the main, it is a class variable (also referred to as a field). You also did not give it an access modifier, so the default will be used (package private). So it will be accessible from a class in the same package. As GhostCat stated, this is a very basic concept.

Comment: yup, sorry im a very beginner in programming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `var1` as a local variable in `Test1`, so it's only available in the local scope. To access the variable from outside the class, you'd have to set it as a property on the class:

```
public class Test1 {

    public String var1 = "Only a test!";

    static int main() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, of course, you wouldn't be able to assign this variable from main because it's an instance variable and `main` is static (The static method wouldn't know which instance to assign the value to).

So, instead, you would make the property static as well:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static String var1;

    static int main(String[] args) {
        var1 = "This is a test!"; // Set var1 first
        Test2.Test2(args); // The call function that does something with var1
    }
}
```

And then you would access the static property from `Test2` like so:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void Test2(String[] args) {
        String source = Test1.var1;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering, but why i still got null?

Comment: I reread you question. I think it's because you're using var1 before you're assigning it. Make sure you do `var1 = "This is a test!";` *before* you call `Test2.Test2(args);` I've updated my answer to show this. Your original code had the order backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can create in that way..

**Test1.java**

```
 package beiobligasi;

    public class Test1 {
    static String var1;
            public static void main( String args[] ) {
              var1 = "Only test!";                
              Test2.Test2(args);
            }
        }
```

First you have to create `String variable` on class level because we can access the `class property` using class object or class name. If you create `variable` inside `main method` so you can not access them using class object or name. So first declare `variable` on class level than initialize them in `main method`.

In above code you need to initialize `var1` before to call `Test2 class static method`.

**Test2.java**

```
package beiobligasi;

public class Test2 {
    static void Test2(String[] args) {
        String source = new Test1().var1;
        System.out.println("Testing result = " + source);
    }
}
```

here you can access your `var1` variable value using either class object or class name.

Comment: thankyou for answering! but why i got null for the result? i want to get the "Only test!" as the result...

Comment: @NWD You need to initialize your variable before call the method.

Comment: @NWD You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)